# xml file created outside of Eclipse won't validate

Tags: xml, eclipse, xml-validation

I have 2 XML files containing the exact same XML data (or at least they do now), the first I created outside of eclipse and copied it into the workspace.

The second was created using the eclipse XML wizard.

In the first file the XML allways fails validation with this error...

> Referenced file contains errors
>   (file:/X:/GLUCODEX/BaseDevel/DB_Logic.xsd).

when I click show details I get this....

> The errors below were detected when validating the file "DB_Logic.xsd"
>   via the file "GlucodexDCheck.xml".  In most cases these errors can be
>   detected by validating "DB_Logic.xsd" directly.  However it is
>   possible that errors will only occur when DB_Logic.xsd is validated in
>   the context of GlucodexDCheck.xml.

if the contents are the same how do I link the first file to get it to validate, remember the contents of the 2 files are exactly the same. With the exception that one is linked to a file in a separate location

The error message shows that the file is being found in the correct location. When I valideate the XSD in eclipse it validates OK.

I'm guessing it is somehow related to the wizard creating the link in to the XSD etc, but I can't find how to add this in to my original file.

thanks in advance for your help.

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finaly found the solution.

I created a new project within eclipse just for the development of static web pages and any XSD schemas I may need.

I then copied the current XSD files into this project, and then used the < window - preferences - XML - XML catalog > to add these files as a user specified entry.

I can now include these files as an entry whenever I need to in other projects.

Brill, all the validations work, and now I have all my CSS, XSD and other commun stuff in a sensible location...

Now all I need is to get maven working again...

Being a tumbleweed was fun whilst it lasted!

David